# Is data masking available in IBM DataWorks Data Load API?

Tags: ibm-cloud, data-masking, dataconnect

Can you implement data masking when using IBM DataWorks Data Load API to protect confidential information?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, IBM DataWorks Data Load supports data masking. The information on how to accomplish this can be found in DataWorks API documentation [Integrating the Data Load REST API into your application](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#services/dataworks1/index-gentopic1.html). Here is an excerpt of that document:

> ... If you classify the data in a source column as sensitive, Data Load masks the data in that column when it is moved to the target

**Note:** This question was [answered on *dW Answers*](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/186911/is-data-masking-available-in-dataworks.html) by user jcantella.